# Error Message: Main.c|6|error: expected identifier or '(' before 'A'

Tags: c

I'm getting an error message when I try to compile my code. I got is

> "main.c|6|error: expected identifier or '(' before 'A'"

Here is my code (I'm learning C as a Beginner from an ebook I downloaded (name is *Beginning Programming with C for Dummies*)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int code;
    char 'A', 'B', 'C';

    printf("Enter the error code (A-C): ");
    scanf("%d",&code);

    switch(code)
    {
        case 'A':
            puts("Drive Fault, not your fault.");
            break;
        case 'B':
            puts("Illegal format, call a lawyer.");
            break;
        case 'C':
            puts("Bad filenane, spank it.");
            break;
        default:
            puts("That's not A, B, or C.");
    }
    return(0);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: delete `char 'A', 'B', 'C';`

Comment: `char code;` ... `scanf("%c",&code);`

Comment: With `scanf("%d", &code)`, the user will have to type "65" to generate an `A`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a closing brace `}` after `return 0;` Which is the closing brace for main().

**+**

Also, to declare a variable such as char A; You need it to be in the form of `<type> [name];`
Example: `char a;` or char `a='A';`

First you need to declare and name a variable before assigning a value such as `'A'` to it.

As for the `switch` statement, it works like this:

switch(var)
{
case 'A':
break;
}

`var` is the variable that you're going to be testing.

`case 'A':` means that when `var` is equal to `'A'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
int main() 
{ 
int code; 
printf("Enter the error code (A-C): ");
scanf("%c",&code);

switch(code)
{
    case 'A':
        puts("Drive Fault, not your fault.");
        break;
    case 'B':
        puts("Illegal format, call a lawyer.");
        break;
    case 'C':
        puts("Bad filenane, spank it.");
        break;
    default:
        puts("That's not A, B, or C.");
}
return(0);
}
```

Closing `}` was not added and `char 'A', 'B', 'C';` was assigned that's why error was getting

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a closing brace after your return

perhaps you meant `char a, b, c` to declare three char variables `a, b and c`